# Using CONCAT with Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I want to use concat with eloquent , I have two tables (users) and (cars)
From users table I want to use first_name , last_name fields, and from cars table I want to use  field called (vin).

```
$cars   = Car::where(DB::raw('concat(first_name," ",vin," ",make)') , 'LIKE' , '%$search%')->paginate();
```

first_name field from Users table and the rest from Cars table

Comment: please post your code, concat with eloquent you can  do it with relation model, you need do some change in your migrations, and insert relation function in yout model User and Car

Comment: I did relation between Users and Cars , one to many ,  and it works fine with me with any queries

Comment: user hasMany , and car belongTo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`join()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#joins) for this as:

```
$cars   = Car::join('users', 'cars.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->where(DB::raw('concat(users.first_name," ",cars.vin," ",cars.make)') , 'LIKE' , "%$search%")
            ->select('cars.*')
            ->paginate();
```

Comment: I did some changes with '%$search%'  which is '%'.$search.'%'

Comment: If you use double quotes then you can do that also as: `"%$search%"`

Comment: Also it works with (first_name," ",vin," ",make)

Thank you so much Amit